# Low internet speed when connected to ethernet

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I'm experiencing slow internet with my raspbery pi 3 B+
My internet speed is 200 Mb/s

I can test it with my mac.

Basically, I try to download this [1 GB File](http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip)

On Mac with both ethernet and wifi, I get around 20 MB/s with is quite OK.

On Raspberry Pi 3 B+, when connected with Wifi, I am around 8 - 10 MB/s

On Raspberry Pi 3 B+, when connected with Ethernet, I am around 2 - 3 MB/s

The cable are ok, as they are working with Mac. Anyway, I tried 2 cables just to be sure.

What could be happening ?

Comment: do you have any USB devices connected.

Comment: Yes 1 hdd 2tb and 1 SSD 250 gb

Comment: and your download, are you saving it to one of these devices?

Comment: For this test, I used microsd

Comment: can you try disconnecting all USB devices ... I believe the ethernet port on the pi "shares" bandwidth with USB (i.e. it's a USB device)

Comment: I unplugged everything including wireless USB mouse / keyboard, but still the same low speed :(